# How to perform full system restore on Ubuntu 12.04 removing all software footprints

Tags: uninstall, system, restore

How to go about performing system restore in Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) so that it also remove all software footprints as well. My system has only Ubuntu and is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent guide here http://news.softpedia.com/news/Installing-Ubuntu-12-04-LTS-266201.shtml
I just had to do this myself, I put my install media and followed **3. Erase and use the entire disk (Erase Ubuntu x.x and reinstall)** in the aforementioned link.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Backintime.  Note that you have to create a snapshot before you are able to restore anything (you can do so manually before trying new software or use it on a schedule).  So I guess in your case it is too late.

Other solutions could include just copying the whole drive or the `/` folder (maybe excluding `/media`) using programs like `clonezilla` or `dd`.  But I think for your purpose Backintime is just fine.

--
Hey, I originally wrote I strongly disagree with the stuff Josea posted.  Why was that deleted?  I absolutely do not understand why there should be no criticizing people who obviously do not have a clue (or don't understand the question) but post "solutions" that can be very dangerous to people's data.  ("how to restore a system? - delete everything!")